# very long nginx initial connection time on site

Tags: php, linux, nginx, amazon-elb

I am using nginx web server and using ELB.

I am getting Very long nginx initial connection time on site. It doesn't happen all the time, but very frequently. I checked in /var/log/nginx/host.access.log file its taking very long time for logging, so I think it's not nginx issue.

Can it be ELB issue?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: We need a reproducible test case. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.